# Is there an adjective that means 'fit to be rejected'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was writing something earlier today, and wanted to say something along these lines:

> "...and found the idea to be rejectionable".

But of course rejectionable is not a word.

Just as: -

> 1. laughable means so ludicrous as to be amusing
> 2. and debatable means open to discussion or argument

Is there are an adjective to describe the quality of being 'fit for rejection' or 'able to be rejected'?

The closest I could find cross referencing synonyms was rebuffable, from the noun: -

> [Rebuff](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rebuff)  noun
>
> 1. a blunt or abrupt rejection, as of a person making advances.
> 2. a peremptory refusal of a request, offer, etc.; snub.
> 3. a check to action or progress.

But this is too specialized a sense of rejection for my use.

Can you think of an adjective that conveys the quality of being 'fit for rejection' or 'able to be rejected'?

Comment: Maybe Defective?

Comment: How about "rejectable"? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rejectable

Comment: unacceptable...

Comment: @Gutavson This may well be what I was looking for thanks. Oxford doesn't list any adjectives for reject. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reject ;neither do Cambridge http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reject , I dont have a subscription to MW so can't view the link you posted , but i see the entry in dictionary.com http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reject

Comment: There's a subtle difference between rejection and reject ; in that rejection is the process of being rejected, and for some reason rejectionable (even though it isn't a word) seems to be the form of word I am trying to find, it has a more active feel to it, than rejectable. If that makes any sense at all?! For sure however, rejectable is almost perfect I would say, and I very much doubt there is going to be a better word to match this.

Comment: Wrt ideas, *dismissible* works.

Comment: You might wanted to say you "rejected the idea out of hand", or rejected it as silly, illogical, or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "unsuitable" on for size.

Merriam-Webster says:

not fitting or right for a use or purpose: not suitable; an unsuitable choice; unsuitable topics for conversation

Answer (score 2):

*disposable*
*discardable*
*useless*
*excludable*
*unworkable*
*dismissible*
*untenable*
*unsustainable*

English has a great many words, some of which  seem to mean the same thing, but do have subtle differences.

> "...and found the idea to be rejectionable".

Only the author knows the exact thought, and word, required here. And, only the author would know that an exact word is required.
I would use:

> "...and found the idea to be *unworkable*".

as it is pragmatic and suggests both rejection and  a reason for rejection.

Answer (score 1):

The word that appears to be the closest adjectival match is 'rejectable'.

This can be achieved by adding the suffix '-able'.

> capable of being rejected : suitable for rejection

Citation:
“Rejectable.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rejectable. Accessed 2 Mar. 2023.

Answer (score 1):

"fit to be rejected":  **unfit**